# aligning text in a span tag wrapping incorrectly

Tags: css

This is part of a more complex dynamic template code so I'm trying to keep the structure as is but trying to style the text so that the cast members line up with the directors below.
Right now the cast gets wrapped to 3 lines but it does not keep its indenting. Anyone know how I could style it to hold its indented look.

http://jsfiddle.net/N2y88/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/N2y88/2/

try something like this

```
.support p span:first-child {
    color: #81848A;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50px;
    float:left;
}
.support p span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}
.support .cast, .support .director{
    color:blue;
}

.support p {
    color: #D0D0D0;
    margin: inherit;
    padding: 0.1em 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: :last-child support is a bit dodgy in IE, however if you define .support p span and than use the :first-child (which has ie 7+ support i believe) to redefine the width to 50 and add the other attributes. http://jsfiddle.net/N2y88/3/ would address this.

Comment: Or you could use `.support p span+span` to define styles for any span which is a sibling to a span.